# Windows image viewer with greyscale and sepia preview at once

Tags: windows, image-viewer

I'm looking for a program to view my photos but I'd like to see at once:

1. original photo
2. grey preview
3. sepia preview

So, at first, I have a list of thumbnails of images in a folder. Then when I click (or double click) an image I see preview of this image as is and in the sidebar the same preview but greyscaled and sepia (both smaller).

Main usage: browsing photos taken and see if one photo looks better as grey or sepia.

I don't need any editing capabilities. Saving grey or sepia version as a new image would be a nice feature. Image file manipulation (especially delete a file) would me nice feature but not required.

Currently, I use XnView and this is more than enough for me to browse images except it does not have the grey/sepia preview.

The software would be for home (private) use. Thus, I'd prefer it for free or very small fee (like 10 $) with a trial period.

**Summary**

- Type:
- image viewer
- OS:
- Windows
- Must have:
- greyscale and sepia preview at once
- move to next/previous image in folder with keyboard
- preview of jpg images
- Nice to have:
- save grey/sepia preview to new file
- file manipulation
- image manipulation
- show file metadata (like filename, EXIF) - easily turn on/off
- preview of RAW images (Canon 70D)
- Usage:
- home (not commercial)
- Accepted fee:
- upto 10 $, preferably free
- accept ad-ware

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, just for others searching for the same:
Use whatever image viewer you like (I recommend XnView MP or FastStone) and turn on the greysale color filter shortcut key in the Windows 10 settings.
Then you can switch between greyscale view with windows+control+C